# What is prop in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was reading the [React's Tic-Tac-Toe
Tutorial](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#setup-for-the-tutorial:%7E:text=className%3D%22square%22%20is%20a%20button%20property%20or%20prop%20that%20tells%20CSS%20how%20to%20style%20the%20button) and I saw this sentence

> `className="square"` is a button property or prop that tells CSS how to style the button

I was confused, props seems to be the values passed in to components. Why is here `className="square"` a prop? It's an attribute, isn't it?

Comment: [Props are the information that you pass to a JSX tag. For example,`className`, `src`, `alt`, `width`, and `height` are some of the props you can pass to an `<img>`:](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component)

Comment: It's worth remembering that while JSX is formatted to look like HTML, it is actually just a syntax for creating JS objects. What would be an attribute in HTML, is a property on the JS object that represents that HTML.